# New DateTime, but with the current hour

Tags: php, datetime

I've got a method which can return me the current datetime, or another one depending on a given date.

I want to set the other date to the same time as now.

Here's my code :

```
/**
 * @param string $date
 * @return string
 */
function getDateFormatted($date = '')
{
    if (preg_match('#^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$#', $date)) {
        $currentDate = new DateTime();
        $date        = new DateTime($date);
        $date->setTime(
            $currentDate->format('H'),
            $currentDate->format('i'),
            $currentDate->format('s')
        );
    } else {
        $date = new DateTime();
    }

    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

$date      = getDateFormatted();
$otherDate = getDateFormatted('2017-09-01');
```

It works, but it bugs me to have to use the `$currentDate` to extract its hours, minutes and seconds.

Is there another, neater way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), all information *not present in the format* will be set to the current time. It also saves you the manual format verification. So:

```
function getFormattedDate($date) {
    $ts = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date) ?: new DateTime;
    return $ts->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: Wow ! Works like a charm, I'll validate it as soon as I can.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using strtotime. It will allow you to simply add the amount of time you would like, for example:

```
strtotime("+1 day")
```

It will accept lots of different input such as: +1 day, +3 days, +1 week, +1 month, +1 week 5 days, etc.

PHP Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: I'd still need to calculate the difference between the format and the current date, I' dont know if that would save me lots of lines of code.